# indexing json file using solr

Tags: json, indexing, solr

I am able to index a simple JSON using solr but for complex JSON which are having nested structures like below I am getting an error. I am using the curl command to index the JSON file using solr:

```
curl 'https://localhost:8983/solr/json_collection/update?commit=true' --data-binary @/home/mic.json -H 'Content-type:application/json'
```

Error:

> Error - {"responseHeader":{"status":400,"QTime":12},"error":{"metadata":["error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException"],"msg":"Error parsing JSON field value. Unexpected OBJECT_START","code":400}}

JSON:

```
[
  {
    "PART I, ITEM 1. BUSINESS": {
      "GENERAL": {
        "Our vision": {
          "text": [
            "Microsoft world."
          ]
        },
        "The ambitions that drive us": {
          "text": [
            "To carry ambitions:",
            "* Create more personal computing."
          ],
          "Create more personal computing": {
            "text": [
              "We strive  available. website."
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      "ITEM 1A. RISK FACTORS": "Our opk."
    }
  }
]
```

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pxz4k.png)

[JSON](https://i.stack.imgur.com/62qan.png)

Comment: what is the error u are getting. ?

Comment: Please click on the error link above to see the error message . Thanks!

Comment: if it is single record remove [ ] from the JSON and try.

Comment: pulled images into post as text to facilitate indexing of content, used correct format for existing code and error quote - it's not good to screen shot code for SO, please copy and paste it into your questions and answers so that the content can be indexed and the content can be found by searching.  Please double check I haven't made any typos; I'm pretty sure I haven't and I have left the links to the original images at the bottom of this post for the time being for my work to be checked.  Once it's OK the links to the images can be removed.

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON seems to be erroneous. In either of the cases, single object or array of JSON, your JSON should follow basic conventions.

In case of single object, the syntax should be-

```
{ "key":"value"}
```

In case of Array of JSON, the syntax can be-

```
{
"key1":["value1", "value2",...],
"key2":["value12", "value22",...]
}
```

Comment: The json structure you mentioned is a simple json that I am able to index but the the places where I have nested key value pairs solr is throwing errror while indexing .

Comment: please share some valid nested JSON, so that we can try to debug the issue